# Magento: Different langues store with different content to update

Tags: magento-1.9, category, configuration

I need to create different stores for different languages and want to add independent content/description for each store in every product and categories. 
For example: I have 3 website:

1. 1st is main website ie in English
2. 2nd is in spanish
3. 3rd in Portuguese.

Requirement: I want to add category description in 3 languages ie. .spanish,Portuguese and english(default) for same category.Same like this:

1. Spanish store/site should display category description in spanish
2. Portuguese store/site should display category description in Portuguese
3. English (degalut) store/site should display category description in English and so on.

System specification: magento version 1.9 and already setup different stores.

Comment: Just change the scope level in the top left dropdown.

Comment: I didnt understand. Can you please elaborate

Comment: I understood that and didnt think its so easy. A big thanks @Claudiu. Answer accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the scope level in the top left dropdown (chose store view):
[image]

If there is no option there than make sure that the stores use the same root category: (system -> manage stores)

Comment: I want to implement same thing for cms,static block as I done with categories description. Is it possible ?

Comment: @Jai yes, of course. you have to select the store associated with a page or a static block

Comment: Dear @Claudiu  ...could you please look at other question i posted. Its here

http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/78871/29175