# Mulitple store: Same CMS and static pages but loads different content for different stores

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, store-view, static-block, cms-block

Multiple stores (version 1.9): I can add category description individually for each store and it will display individually for specific stores.

Requirement: I want same functionality for CMS and Static pages. If i change content of any cms or static page then it should reflect in specific site not on all sub-stores. 
Note: I want to use single and same page for all stores but changes should reflect individually like it happened for categories description.

Urgent help required.

Answer (score 0):

For separate cms pages you will need to set up individual pages for each view and set the store view within the page info tab.

Comment: I know this but cant we do same like we can do in categories description for all stores?

Comment: Unfortunately not if you don't want to use this approach you could create each page and use magentos translation to use a single page for multiple stores

Comment: I hope i could make sense in question?   Actually i want indepedent content for every store. You can suggest another alternative if possible.  Thanks

Comment: To get this done you would have to create separate pages per view as stated in Magento documentation http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#cms/page-translate.html%3FTocPath%3DContent%2520Elements%7CContent%2520Pages%7C_____5